# Tag Split: Monitors

Tags: discussion

Should we split Monitors in to two separate tags?  Currently the Monitor tag describes the role of both reference monitors (monitors used to judge accuracy) and playback monitors (monitors used to see what is going on, but not necessarily concerned with accuracy).

Answer (score 3):

I propose that at a minimum a reference-monitor tag should be created and the description of monitor should be made more generic to the performance/playback use case.

Comment: This seems sensible to me. 'monitors' becomes a bit of a meta-tag unless made more specific, from the looks of it (no pun intended)